# How to specify output file cell format when using ssconvert --merge-to to create ODS file from multiple CSVs?

Tags: csv, date-format, gnumeric

I successfully converted a series of `.csv` files into a single .ods spreadsheet file, but I had a minor formatting problem: all cells with **date contents** ended up with **date and time format**. Command used:

```
ssconvert --merge-to dir/output_file.ods dir/*.csv
```

Is there a way to tell `ssconvert` to use **only date instead** for those cells?

Thanks!